# How to determine why there was a reboot

Tags: linux, boot, reboot

After a boot/reboot, is there a way of figuring out why there was a reboot? I can think of some reasons I would like to detect:

- Automatic reboot due to system upgrade
- Powerfailure
- User run `sudo reboot`
- Power/reset button pressed
- ...

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to look in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages` (depending on Linux distro) for clues, but it's not something that's specifically tracked by any Linux I've encountered.

- I've never seen any Linux do an automatic reboot due to system upgrade, but I would expect the initiating process to log it if that were to happen.
- Power failure is just going to cause an abrupt stop to all logging, since the system can't log anything without power.  The exception is if you have a UPS and it signals the machine to shut down cleanly after power loss, in which case there should be logs saying that the message was received from the UPS and shutdown was initiated.
- `sudo` commands are logged in `/var/log/auth.log` (`[timestamp] [hostname] sudo: [user]: TTY=[tty] ; PWD=[pwd] ; USER=root ; COMMAND=[command]`)  Note that, if the user runs `sudo -i`, `sudo bash`, or the like, the `COMMAND` field won't tell you what they did (e.g., `poweroff`), but you can still compare timestamps and see that they were in `sudo` when the shutdown/reboot occurred.
- Power/reset button pressed may be logged, provided that the kernel is properly configured to receive and recognize ACPI events (which it probably will be these days).

Comment: If I remember correctly: the last times I installed Ubuntu I have been asked by the installer if I wanted to configure the system to automatically install security-updates. If asking yes to that (which is the default I think) you get this I think https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades